# Symfony 6 collection remove item javascript

Tags: javascript, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony6

I have a form with a collection in Symfony 6 where it is possible to add and delete items. Adding and removing a collection works. The problem is only if an error is rendered in the form (`$form->addError(new FormError('Some Error'));`). At that point, the link to remove the collection will be lost, but the items will still be rendered. What is needed so that the "remove" link does not disappear?

```js
const addTagLink = document.createElement('a')
addTagLink.classList.add('add')
addTagLink.href = '#'
addTagLink.innerText = 'Add'
addTagLink.dataset.collectionHolderClass = 'items'

const collectionHolder = document.querySelector('ul.items')
collectionHolder.appendChild(addTagLink)

const addFormToCollection = (e) => {
  const collectionHolder = document.querySelector('.' + e.currentTarget.dataset.collectionHolderClass);

  const item = document.createElement('li');

  item.innerHTML = collectionHolder
    .dataset
    .prototype
    .replace(
      /__name__/g,
      collectionHolder.dataset.index
    );

  collectionHolder.appendChild(item);
  collectionHolder.dataset.index++;

  const removeLink = document.createElement('a');
  removeLink.href = '#';
  removeLink.innerText = 'Remove';
  removeLink.classList.add('remove');

  item.appendChild(removeLink);

  removeLink.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    item.remove();
  })
}

addTagLink.addEventListener("click", addFormToCollection)
```

```html
<form name="expedition" method="post">
  <div>
    <ul class="items" data-index="0" data-prototype="&lt;div&#x20;id&#x3D;&quot;expedition_items___name__&quot;&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;label&#x20;class&#x3D;&quot;block&#x20;text-sm&#x20;font-medium&#x20;text-gray-700&#x20;required&quot;&#x20;for&#x3D;&quot;expedition_items___name___quantity&quot;&gt;Quantity&lt;&#x2F;label&gt;&lt;input&#x20;type&#x3D;&quot;text&quot;&#x20;id&#x3D;&quot;expedition_items___name___quantity&quot;&#x20;name&#x3D;&quot;expedition&#x5B;items&#x5D;&#x5B;__name__&#x5D;&#x5B;quantity&#x5D;&quot;&#x20;required&#x3D;&quot;required&quot;&#x20;class&#x3D;&quot;block&#x20;w-full&#x20;shadow-sm&#x20;border-gray-300&#x20;rounded-md&#x20;border&#x20;p-2&#x20;mt-1&#x20;mb-2&quot;&#x20;inputmode&#x3D;&quot;decimal&quot;&#x20;&#x2F;&gt;&lt;&#x2F;div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;label&#x20;class&#x3D;&quot;block&#x20;text-sm&#x20;font-medium&#x20;text-gray-700&#x20;required&quot;&#x20;for&#x3D;&quot;expedition_items___name___product&quot;&gt;Product&lt;&#x2F;label&gt;&lt;select&#x20;id&#x3D;&quot;expedition_items___name___product&quot;&#x20;name&#x3D;&quot;expedition&#x5B;items&#x5D;&#x5B;__name__&#x5D;&#x5B;product&#x5D;&quot;&#x20;required&#x3D;&quot;required&quot;&#x20;class&#x3D;&quot;block&#x20;w-full&#x20;shadow-sm&#x20;border-gray-300&#x20;rounded-md&#x20;border&#x20;p-2&#x20;mt-1&#x20;mb-2&quot;&gt;&lt;option&#x20;value&#x3D;&quot;&quot;&#x20;selected&#x3D;&quot;selected&quot;&gt;Choose&#x20;a&#x20;product&lt;&#x2F;option&gt;&lt;option&#x20;value&#x3D;&quot;2&quot;&gt;Product&#x20;1&lt;&#x2F;option&gt;&lt;option&#x20;value&#x3D;&quot;3&quot;&gt;Product&#x20;2&lt;&#x2F;option&gt;&lt;&#x2F;select&gt;&lt;&#x2F;div&gt;&lt;&#x2F;div&gt;">
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

twig

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{% if form_errors(form) %}
<div class="rounded-md p-2 border-red-300 bg-red-50 border mb-4">{{ form_errors(form) }}</div>
{% endif %}
<div>
    <ul class="items"
        data-index="{{ form.items|length > 0 ? form.items|last.vars.name + 1 : 0 }}"
        data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.items.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
                <li class="item">
                    {{ form_label(form.items) }}
                    {{ form_widget(form.items) }}
                    {{ form_errors(form.items) }}
               <li>
    </ul>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="block w-full shadow-sm border-transparent bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 dark:gb-indigo-500 dark:hover:bg-indigo-400 text-white rounded-md border p-2 mt-4 mb-2">{{ 'Save'|trans }}</button>

{{ form_end(form)}}
```

Comment: How do you render the submitted collection items when the form needs to be re-displayed with an error? I would expect a loop or a `{{ form_row(collection) }}` inside the template - then that's where you would need to add the delete link. Or do you maybe add the errors via JavaScript? Please show more code. :)

Comment: I added a template for rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Render your items in a loop to give each item its own `<li>`:

```
    <ul class="items"
        data-index="{{ form.items|length > 0 ? form.items|last.vars.name + 1 : 0 }}"
        data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.items.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
        {% for itemForm in form.items %}
            <li class="item">
                {{ form_label(itemForm) }}
                {{ form_widget(itemForm) }}
                {{ form_errors(itemForm) }}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Then create a JavaScript function that adds a remove link to a given item:

```
    const addItemFormDeleteLink = (item) => {
        const removeLink = document.createElement('a');
        removeLink.href = '#';
        removeLink.innerText = 'Remove';
        removeLink.classList.add('remove');

        item.appendChild(removeLink);

        removeLink.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            item.remove();
        })
    }
```

And use this to add the remove link to the existing items on the page:

```
    document
        .querySelectorAll('ul.items li')
        .forEach((tag) => {
            addItemFormDeleteLink(tag)
        })
```

And in `addFormToCollection`:

```
    const addFormToCollection = (e) => {
        const collectionHolder = document.querySelector('.' + e.currentTarget.dataset.collectionHolderClass);

        const item = document.createElement('li');

        item.innerHTML = collectionHolder
            .dataset
            .prototype
            .replace(
            /__name__/g,
            collectionHolder.dataset.index
            );

        collectionHolder.appendChild(item);
        collectionHolder.dataset.index++;

        // add a delete link to the new form
        addItemFormDeleteLink(item);
    }
```

See also: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html#allowing-tags-to-be-removed